# How to make the content written to Excel in a loop not overwritten by the previous one

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Extract data from multiple word tables and write them into the same sheet in Excel.

```
path = 'folder path'
worddocs_list = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    wordDoc = Document(path+'\\'+filename)
    worddocs_list.append(wordDoc)
    
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("./test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

i = 0
for wordDoc in worddocs_list:
    for table in wordDoc.tables:
        lst = []
        for row in table.rows[5:6]:
            row_lst = []
            for cell in row.cells[1:7]:
                c = cell.text
                row_lst.append(c)
            lst.append(row_lst)
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        N = 6
        split_list = np.array_split(lst, N, axis=0)
        for i in range(N):
            df.loc[0, 'Column_{}'.format(i)] = split_list[0][0][i]
        print(df)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet{1}')
    i += 1

writer.save()
```

In the TEST file, only the content of the last loop. How to write ‘ROW+1’ in each loop, thank you!!

Comment: Are you trying to save each table to a different sheet? If so, you probably want `df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"Sheet{i}")` instead of `f"Sheet{1}"` -- note the use of `i` instead of `1`.

Comment: I'd like to save the 'cell.text' in one same sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are taking just one row from each table. You can gather all of these rows together and then do one write at the end.

```py
out_rows = [
    [c.text for c in table.rows[5].cells[1:7]]
    for wordDoc in worddocs_list
    for table in wordDoc.tables
]

df = pd.DataFrame(out_rows, columns=[f"Column_{i}" for i in range(6)])
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet{1}')
```